# Fast union of shapes in Java

Tags: java, geometry, union, shapes

I am working on a library for extracting outlines of SVG images. Using Batik in Java makes the process of transforming the SVG file into expanded shapes (`java.awt.geom.Shape` instances) a charm -- for a relatively complex shape we're on the order of milliseconds for this operation. However, as I need a combined outline, I create a `java.awt.geom.Area` and union each of the shapes using `.add(shape)`. Unexpectedly, this is incredibly slow even for relatively simple shapes. By "incredibly" I mean on the order of 36 seconds to add together 8 shapes of 6-10 points per shape.

Running the code with `-Xrunhprof` hints that a majority of time is spent in `java.awt.geom.AreaOp.pruneEdges(..)` with `java.lang.StrictMath.acos` being the biggest culprit. Combining an alternative implementation ([`AreaX`](https://javagraphics.java.net/doc/com/bric/geom/AreaX.html)) with `FastMath` has only yielded insignificant improvements while my search for Java libraries for handling arbitrary geometrical shapes has come up empty.

The question then is, what is the way to go about creating a union of shapes in Java without this insane performance penalty? Is there some library or approach that can help the performance of this -- seemingly -- simple operation?

Comment: You were right to let "seemingly" between dashes. This is an awfully delicate operation due to numerical issues and complex topological changes. Anyway, 36 seconds looks pathological. Are you sure that the Area items that you combine only have a handful of vertices ?

Comment: Yea, I'm sure (I've checked.) The problem seems to be in the sweep line approach used as some shapes seem to produce very slow sweep line progress.

Comment: This sounds very mysterious. I was thinking of vertex count explosion caused by discretized curves (like Bezier or rounded endpoints turned into polylines). Besides that, it is hard to explain why few points can cause such long delays. Even poorly implemented scanline taking, say, O(N^3) operations would be far from explaining such a slow speed. Are there curves in your shapes ? (If yes, the reason could lie in slow convergence of iterative intersection algorithms, or excessive accuracy tolerances.)

Comment: Yes, the shape consists mainly of curves. I see on the order of 2.5 million allocations of CurveLink instances during the operation (consuming upwards of 500 MiB in total).

Comment: Then you might improve by adjusting tolerances if the API supports that, or scaling your coordinates. (How big are they ?) It could also be that your case is pathological, for instance two outlines very very close to each other but not exactly. Can I see your SVG ?

Answer (score 6):

You can try to create a `java.awt.geom.Path2D` (`Path2D.Float` or `Path2D.Double`), append your Shapes to it and create an Area using that path. 
This way is much faster than adding shapes to an Area but I'm not 100% sure if the results are exactly the same.
Something like:

```
            List<Shape> shapes = ....
            Path2D path = new Path2D.Float();
            for (Shape shape : shapes) {
              path.append(shape, false);
            }
            Area compound = new Area(path);
```

Comment: The speed difference is amazing (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4150) and no difference in the result, so thank you! My application is union of glyph shapes, so I have a lot of curves.

Comment: Wow, I see you got BIG performance gains. I'm happy this was useful for you. Thank you very much for your comment and the mention in the jira page.

Comment: Note this doesn't work if your area has holes.

Comment: Old post but this is just brilliant and solved problem for me (union of complex shapes without holes)

Comment: By the way, if you have holes, you can apply this trick to all the outer rings and inner rings separately in two Path2Ds, and then use one Area.subtract to create the correct result.